# command line Mac OS X pass over WARNING message

Tags: macos, shell, warnings

I was running a program in my terminal (in Mac OS X 10.9.5). And it stops because the input file that I have provided are not exactly as it requires, writing a WARN message.

So If I type control-C, the program continues to work, although the WARN message. In the end I obtain the output file that I needed.

The point is that I would like to find a command to put in a script that allow me to pass over the WARNING message, without typing control+C manually.

Comment: is this program's source code something you have access to?

Comment: no, the name of the program is PGDSpider2. The strange thing is that, typing control+C and then Key

Comment: The program appears to be written in Java.  I suggest you contact the support links specified here: http://www.cmpg.unibe.ch/software/PGDSpider/